# Failing cucumber test after upgrading rails to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

This one has had me stumped for a couple of days..

I have a cucumber test which fails with rails 3.2.11 but passes on rails 3.2.3. I'm getting a no route matches error however when I go through the exact same steps manually on the website it works.

My routes are -

```
    get 'reward_player/:id' => 'reward_players#show', :as => :reward_player
```

And the error I am getting is

```
    No route matches {:controller=>"admin/reward_player", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}
```

My step to visit this page is just click_link "Reward Player". When I use save_and_open_page to view the page the id is in the link. I'm really not sure what is going on or if it is a test that should have always been failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being my route, it should have been

```
   get 'reward_player/:user_id' => 'reward_players#show', :as => :reward_player
```

seeing as the controller was looking for a user_id in the params. So ended up being a test that shouldn't have really pass to start with.